# How to sort the list of tuples first by the descending order and alphabetically simultaneously in python 3?

Tags: python, sorting, python-3.x

If I have a list of tuples, where the first is number, and second is a string, for example:

```
[(2, 'eye'), (4, 'tail'), (1, 'scarf'), (4,'voice')]
```

How can I sort it in descending order by the number and If there is a tie in number at any point, the words with the same number should be sub-sorted alphabetically. And return the final sorted words.

From my example:

```
['tail', 'voice', 'eye', scarf']
```

I sorted them by descending order, but I don't know how to subsort it alphabetically. Will be happy to hear any hint and answer. Thanks!

```
def sorting(list)
   my_list = []
   for x, y in list.items():
     my_list+=[(y,x)]
   sort=sorted(my_list, reverse=True)
```

Answer (score 11):

You can use the `key` argument , move the number (first element) to its negative counter-part and sort that list in ascending order. Example -

```
In [21]: lst = [(2, 'eye'), (4, 'tail'), (1, 'scarf'), (4,'voice')]

In [22]: sorted(lst, key = lambda x: (-x[0],x[1]))
Out[22]: [(4, 'tail'), (4, 'voice'), (2, 'eye'), (1, 'scarf')]
```

To get only the list of words in that order, you can use list comprehension -

```
In [24]: [x[1] for x in sorted(lst, key = lambda x: (-x[0],x[1]))]
Out[24]: ['tail', 'voice', 'eye', 'scarf']
```

Comment: Various sorting questions are answered in [this](https://wiki.python.org/moin/HowTo/Sorting#Ascending_and_Descending) document, which also shows an idiomatic way of using the 'key' parameter.